# Find Heap Corruption In C Program

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, heap-corruption

I've looked around, but most of the answers here are to questions where the heap corruption is obvious from the code, or where the asker has already identified the source.

I have a C program (simulating a car race) that is dynamically allocating memory for a linked list. It then copies values from one or more nodes from the list into a dynamically allocated 2D array, based on a value in the node. Each node is freed after it is copied, and the list head is updated. This repeats until there are no more nodes in the list (the end of the race).

A pointer to the array is returned to main and stored in a 3D array.

The whole process then repeats (new linked list, new array).

At the end of the second iteration (second race), I am getting a heap corruption error, and I can't figure out what is causing it.

I tried using VLD as suggested here: [Memory allocation / Heap corruption in std::string constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557779/memory-allocation-heap-corruption-in-stdstring-constructor/6557811#6557811)

But with VLD included I didn't get the error.

I also tried enabling the debug heap functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx

This told me the address was 0x596EBC5C, which doesn't appear to contain anything I allocated, so I'm not sure if that's meaningful somehow.

The best I can tell, I'm getting the error in this block of code, but I'm not even sure of that, and I don't know how that would help me find the source of the problem.

```
void MoveFinishers(NODE **racehead, int **FinisherList, int raceLength) {
    static int numberOfFinishers = 0;
    NODE *head = *racehead;
    NODE *temp = *racehead;
    NODE *tempNext = NULL;
    while (head != NULL && head->car.distance >= raceLength)
    {
        FinisherList[0][numberOfFinishers] = head->car.number;
        numberOfFinishers++;
        head = head->next; //advance to the next finisher
    }

    *racehead = head; //change the list head to start with the first non-finisher

    //free all list elements before the first non-finisher
    while (temp != head)
    {
        tempNext = temp->next; //iterates through the temp values
        free(temp);
        temp = tempNext;
    } //end while
}
```

Comment: Running your program with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) may be another avenue to explore.

Comment: if you were using Linux, I'd say that Valgrind would probably be able to see when you are doing the bad access. Is it possible for you to compile on a Linux environment?

Comment: *"At the end of the second iteration"* If that's predictable and repeatable with a small number of entries, then you should be able to find it with a debugger.

Comment: @user3386109 It was intermittent, so I set the srand seed to a static value, and I've been able to reproduce it. To be honest though, I'm not really sure what I'm doing with the debugger, at least not at this level. I've never had to find the source of heap corruption with a debugger before.

Comment: `static int numberOfFinishers = 0;` In the second race, won't that start off with the wrong value (not zero but rather the number of cars in the last race)? Because it is static. In any case, you probably should bounds check this: `FinisherList[0][numberOfFinishers]`

Comment: your question seems to indicate a free() with an uninitialized pointer.  perhaps the 'next' field in some node (for instance, the last node) is not initialized to NULL.

Comment: @AlanAu Heh, I actually just posted that as the answer before I read your comment. You are absolutely correct. I feel bad picking my own answer as the best, so if you'd like to post that as an answer, I'd be happy to give you the rep.

Comment: No worries. Keep your answer. It's to be encouraged when anyone puts in the effort to solve their own problems. Good work!

Comment: @AlanAu also, as to bounds checking, I had chosen not to because there is no possibility with the logic of my code for the array size to be different from the number of nodes in the original linked list, as they work off the same source value. On review though, it probably wouldn't hurt that much to do so, since when I last refactored, the caller now has access to that value as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Unfortunately, I still wasn't able to find the problem throught the debugger, but rather just looking at the code.

Anyways, the issue was with this:

```
static int numberOfFinishers = 0
```

I declared it static because I needed it to maintain state within a single race.

However, after the first race, I was not resetting the counter, so this was actually starting to store values in unallocated memory:

```
FinisherList[0][numberOfFinishers]
```

The fix was as simple as adding this to the end of the function:

```
    if (!head)
    {
        numberOfFinishers = 0;
    }
```